# Terraform: Identifying the Latest/Last Resources Created?

Tags: terraform

Is it possible to query the Terraform state reliably to identify the most recently created resource of a given type?

In my use case, I have a CI/CD pipeline deploying resources via "terraform apply", I would like to identify the last resource created (virtual machine) and kick off another pipeline to carry out non-terraform configuration on that virtual server.

Comment: It's not particularly clear what you're trying to do here. Can you provide a [mcve] of what you've got and then explain exactly what you're trying to achieve and what you've tried that isn't working?

Comment: @ ydaetskcoR - I hope my answer below clarifies the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The objective behind my original question is to be able to identify a most recently created resource (virtual machine) from a Terraform run and carry out a second phase of configuration on that resource (e.g run an application installation or operating system hardening process).

The solution is not to think of this procedurally but instead handle it with a tool that works idempotently (e.g Ansible) that runs across all resources created after a terraform run and is smart enough to determine if anything should be done.

So: Simply process terraform  outputs and pass it to a next stage in the pipeline as inventory to Ansible/Puppet/etc

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question and should be an edit to the original question instead.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR - This is indeed the answer to my original question, i.e "Simply process terraform outputs and pass it to a next stage in the pipeline". The clarification included in my answer includes a preamble about the objective of what I was originally trying to do. To make the answer complete, some advice on how to think about the problem is included in the answer, i.e " not to think of this procedurally but instead handle it with a tool that works idempotently (e.g Ansible)"

Comment: That's not a helpful answer for someone else who has your same issue. For reference the answer would normally be either use an orchestrator such as Jenkins to trigger both Terraform and Ansible with either dynamic inventory or some other instance discovery mechanism or to use either user data for configuration (potentially by baking any shared config into the AMI with something like Packer) or to use Terraform's provisioners. Your answer is too vague to be useful and shows no examples of how to do this. If you look at existing questions and answers you should see the standard expected here.